# Is there software available to benchmark networking equipment?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there software, or a utility, available on Ubuntu that I could use to benchmark (performance test) traffic and throughput on networking equipment (specifically Cisco switches or routers)?

Comment: what sort of hardware? what sort of test? (max connections/sec, 450 byte tcp, jumbo frame udp, etc?)

Answer (score 3):

For general throughput testing, I've used `iperf` (`sudo apt-get install iperf`).

You start a server on one machine (using `iperf -s`) and run the client on another machine on the other side of the network. You get a throughput like so:

```
oli@bert:~$ iperf -c tim
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to tim, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.4 port 39402 connected with 192.168.0.5 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.04 GBytes    895 Mbits/sec
```

Answer (score 0):

hdparm -t /dev/disk can be a good indicator as well, if you mount any of the drives on a server on the other side of the device. comparison between local disk speed on the server and disk speed from a client over the network can be a good indicator.